# Shiny: R session aborted when subsetting data

Tags: r, shiny, selectinput

I've created an R shiny app that creates a word cloud for open-ended responses from a survey. This is part of a larger shiny dashboard to analyze a series of large surveys. For one particular survey, when choosing options (from the "Tenure status to View:" drop-down menu), R crashes with the notice "R session aborted". I have had this code work for other data sets. I have tried this exact code with other datasets and it has worked as intended.
Note: the data set provided isn't the actual data set I intend to use with this project (which adds some complications because I think the data set might be part of the problem). That dataset has sensitive information and could not be shared. The data set I am providing was created to look like the data set that I am using and is exhibiting the same problem.

The data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p5OZYbEr5rYNPL1TWoXa_zLNo4INO-4H/view?usp=sharing

```
library(sjmisc)
library(sjlabelled)
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(psych) # for describe and cronbach's alpha
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(shinydashboard)
library(haven)
library(expss)
library(openxlsx)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(SnowballC)
library(wordcloud)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(tm)

sdata=read.xlsx("TestData.xlsx")
OEdata=sdata %>%
    select(Tenure, Challenges, Strategies)

OEdata=expss::modify(OEdata, {
    var_lab(Challenges)="What are the unique challenges of the COVID-19 pandemic that have impacted your research, teaching, and service activities?"
    var_lab(Strategies)="Now that you have made changes to your teaching and research activities as a result of the pandemic, have you found strategies that worked so well that you plan to continue using them after the pandemic?"
})

OElist=vector()
OElist[1]=get_label(OEdata$Challenges)
OElist[2]=get_label(OEdata$Strategies)

TenureList =c("Tenure Status", levels(as.factor(OEdata$Tenure)))

OEdatasplit = list()
for (i in 1:length(TenureList)){
    name = TenureList[i]
    if (i==1){ 
        OEdatasplit[[name]] = OEdata
        OEdatasplit[[name]]  = copy_labels(OEdatasplit[[name]] ,OEdata)
        
    } else {
        OEdatasplit[[name]] = OEdata %>% dplyr::filter(Tenure == name)
        OEdatasplit[[name]]  = copy_labels(OEdatasplit[[name]] ,OEdata)
        
    }
}

ui=dashboardPage(
    
    # skin defines color theme
    skin="blue",
    # title defines name of app
    title="Faculty Experience Survey 2020",
    
    # === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === ==
    #Header =============================================================================
    
    dashboardHeader(
        # information in header bar -- includes logo (image must be in www folder in app directory to work)
        title=div(img(src="Illinois-Logo-Full-Color-RGB.png",
                      height="30",
                      style="margin-bottom:10px"), 
                  "Faculty Experience Survey 2020",
                  # lock the title position
                  style="position: fixed; overflow: visible;"),
        titleWidth=350
    ),
    
    
    # === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === ==
    # Sidebar ============================================================================
    
    dashboardSidebar(
        # define fixed width for sidebar
        width=350,
        
        
        sidebarMenu(
            # name sidebar for reference
            id="sidebarmenu",
            
            # lock the sidebar position
            style="position: fixed; overflow: visible;",
            
            # === === === === === === ===
            # begin sidebar content =====
            # FOR SBC, USER CHOOSES COHORT 
            # populates cohorts list from cohortlist in Global
            selectInput(inputId="Tenure", label="Tenure status to View:", choices=TenureList,
                        selected="Tenure Status", multiple=FALSE, selectize=TRUE),
            
            # sidebar menu items
            # important to include unique tabName!
            menuItem("Responses to Open-ended questions", 
                     tabName="Write-ins", icon=icon("bar-chart")#,
            )
            
        )
    ),
    
    # === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === ==
    # Dashboard body =====================================================================
    
    dashboardBody(
        
        # this code is placed internally to edit other visual features such as box colors
        tags$style(HTML("
                      .box.box-solid.box-primary>.box-header {
                      color:#fff;
                      background:#888888
                      }
                      
                      .box.box-solid.box-primary{
                      border-bottom-color:#888888;
                      border-left-color:#888888;
                      border-right-color:#888888;
                      border-top-color:#888888;
                      }
      ")),
        # ===****===========================
        # RESPONSES TO OPEN-ENDED QUESTIONS ====
        
        tabItem(
            tabName="Write-ins",
            h2("Responses to Open-ended questions"),
            h3("Figures will appear blank if there were no responsed to a question for a specified Cohort and Course"),
            
            # SUPPORTING TABLES AND GRAPHS
            br(),
            
            fluidRow(
                column(width=3,
                       box(title="Select Question(s) to View...",
                           background = "blue",
                           solidHeader=TRUE,width=NULL,
                           div(style="height: 400px; overflow-y: scroll;",
                               actionButton('all','Check All'),
                               actionButton('none','Uncheck All'),
                               checkboxGroupInput("WIList", label=NULL,
                                                  choices = OElist,
                                                  selected = OElist))
                       )) ,
                
                #Challenges======================================================
                column(width=9,
                       conditionalPanel(
                           condition = 'input.WIList.includes("What are the unique challenges of the COVID-19 pandemic that have impacted your research, teaching, and service activities?")',
                           fluidRow(
                               box(title=OElist[1],
                                   width=12, status="primary", solidHeader=TRUE,
                                   # dataTableOutput(test),
                                   plotOutput("Challenges"),
                                   plotOutput("Challenges_FreqGraph"),
                                   br(),
                                   searchInput(
                                       inputId= "Csearch", label="Enter your text",
                                       value = "Search Term",
                                       placeholder = "Search Term",
                                       btnSearch = icon("search"),
                                       btnReset = icon("remove"),
                                       width = "450px"
                                   ),
                                   br(),
                                   # verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "Challenges_Search"),
                                   htmlOutput("Challenges_Search"),
                                   downloadBttn('Challenges_Data', "Download Results")
                               )
                           )
                       ),
                       
                       #end ===
                       br()
                ),
                #Strategies======================================================
                column(width=9,
                       conditionalPanel(
                           condition = 'input.WIList.includes("Now that you have made changes to your teaching and research activities as a result of the pandemic, have you found strategies that worked so well that you plan to continue using them after the pandemic?")',
                           fluidRow(
                               box(title=OElist[2],
                                   width=12, status="primary", solidHeader=TRUE,
                                   # dataTableOutput(test),
                                   plotOutput("Strategies"),
                                   plotOutput("Strategies_FreqGraph"),
                                   br(),
                                   searchInput(
                                       inputId= "Stratsearch", label="Enter your text",
                                       value = "Search Term",
                                       placeholder = "Search Term",
                                       btnSearch = icon("search"),
                                       btnReset = icon("remove"),
                                       width = "450px"
                                   ),
                                   br(),
                                   # verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "Strategies_Search"),
                                   htmlOutput("Strategies_Search"),
                                   downloadBttn("Strategies_Data", "Download Results")
                               )
                           )
                       ),
                       
                       #end ===
                       br()
                )
            )
        ),
    )
)

server=(function(input, output, session) {
    
    # === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === =
    # Add reactivity to the data ==========================================================
    # this will split the data to render data only for the selected cohort(chosen using selectInput in the sidebarMenu)
    
    OEReactive=reactive({
        return(OEdatasplit[[input$Tenure]])
    })
    
    
    # =====****=================================================================================
    ###RESPONSES TO OPEN-ENDED QUESTIONS======================================================
    
    
    #Create the checklist to control which questions appear==================================
    #uncheck all 
    observeEvent(input$none,{
        if (input$none > 0) {
            updateCheckboxGroupInput(session=session, inputId="WIList", choices=OElist, selected=NULL)
        }
    })
    # check all
    observeEvent(input$all,{
        if (input$all > 0) {
            updateCheckboxGroupInput(session=session, inputId="WIList", choices=OElist, selected=OElist)
        }
    })
    
    
    # #Challenges===============================================
    ##Render plot object creates the wordcloud
    output$Challenges= renderPlot({
        ##Subset on Vars
        OpenEnds=OEReactive()
        ChallengesFrame=data.frame(doc_id=1:length(OpenEnds$Challenges), text=OpenEnds$Challenges)
        Challenges=DataframeSource(ChallengesFrame)
        ChallengesCorpus=Corpus(Challenges)
        ##Clean data and add stop words
        # Convert the text to lower case
        ChallengesCorpus <- tm_map(ChallengesCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
        # Remove numbers
        ChallengesCorpus <- tm_map(ChallengesCorpus, removeNumbers)
        # Remove english common stopwords
        ChallengesCorpus <- tm_map(ChallengesCorpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
        # Remove your own stop word
        # specify your stopwords as a character vector
        # ChallengesCorpus <- tm_map(ChallengesCorpus, removeWords, c("like", "course"))
        # Remove punctuations
        ChallengesCorpus <- tm_map(ChallengesCorpus, removePunctuation)
        # Eliminate extra white spaces
        ChallengesCorpus <- tm_map(ChallengesCorpus, stripWhitespace)
        # Text stemming
        # ChallengesCorpus <- tm_map(ChallengesCorpus, stemDocument)
        
        ##Final prep of object for wordcloud
        dtm=TermDocumentMatrix(ChallengesCorpus)
        m=as.matrix(dtm)
        v=sort(rowSums(m), decreasing = T)
        d=data.frame(word=names(v), freq=v)
        
        ##Create and print the wordcloud
        #Won't work if are not enough responses:
        if(nrow(d)!=0){
            Challenges=wordcloud(words = d$word, freq = d$freq, min.freq = 1,
                                 max.words=200, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35,
                                 colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
            print(Challenges)
        }
    })
    #
    output$Challenges_FreqGraph=renderPlot({
        OpenEnds=OEReactive()
        #Repeat of the above
        ChallengesFrame=data.frame(doc_id=1:length(OpenEnds$Challenges), text=OpenEnds$Challenges)
        Challenges=DataframeSource(ChallengesFrame)
        ChallengesCorpus=Corpus(Challenges)
        
        ChallengesCorpus <- tm_map(ChallengesCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
        ChallengesCorpus <- tm_map(ChallengesCorpus, removeNumbers)
        ChallengesCorpus <- tm_map(ChallengesCorpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
        ChallengesCorpus <- tm_map(ChallengesCorpus, removePunctuation)
        ChallengesCorpus <- tm_map(ChallengesCorpus, stripWhitespace)
        dtm=TermDocumentMatrix(ChallengesCorpus)
        m=as.matrix(dtm)
        v=sort(rowSums(m), decreasing = T)
        d=data.frame(word=names(v), freq=v)
        
        topWords=head(d, 20)
        
        if(nrow(d)!=0){
            topWordsGraph=ggplot(topWords, aes(x=reorder(word, -freq), y=freq)) +geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill="#11294B")+
                theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12, angle = 45, hjust=1), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                      panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
                xlab("Examples of Frequently Used Words") +
                ylab("Frequency")+
                ggtitle(get_label(OpenEnds$Challenges))
            print(topWordsGraph)
        }
    })
    
    
    output$Challenges_Search=renderUI({
        OpenEnds=OEReactive()
        OpenEnds=as.data.frame(OpenEnds)
        if(input$Csearch=="Search Term"| input$Csearch==""){
            OEs=""
            HTML(OEs)
        }  else{
            Results=grep(input$Csearch, OpenEnds$Challenges)
            ResultOEs=OpenEnds$Challenges[Results]
            OEs=c()
            for (i in 1:length(ResultOEs)) {
                OEs[i]=paste(ResultOEs[i],"<br/> <br/>")
            }
            HTML(OEs)
        }
    })
    
    output$Challenges_Data=downloadHandler(
        #Code for download
        filename = function(){
            paste("Challenges", ".csv", sep = "")
        },
        content=function(file){
            OpenEnds=OEReactive()
            Results=grep(input$Csearch, OpenEnds$Challenges)
            ResultOEs=OpenEnds$Challenges[Results]
            ResultOEs=as.data.frame(ResultOEs)
            colnames(ResultOEs)=get_label(OpenEnds$Challenges)
            write.csv(ResultOEs, file, row.names = FALSE)
        }
        
    )
    
    #Strategies====================================================
    #Render plot object creates the wordcloud
    output$Strategies= renderPlot({
        ##Subset on Vars
        OpenEnds=OEReactive()
        StrategiesFrame=data.frame(doc_id=1:length(OpenEnds$Strategies), text=OpenEnds$Strategies)
        
        Strategies=DataframeSource(StrategiesFrame)
        
        StrategiesCorpus=Corpus(Strategies)
        StrategiesCorpus <- tm_map(StrategiesCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
        StrategiesCorpus <- tm_map(StrategiesCorpus, removeNumbers)
        StrategiesCorpus <- tm_map(StrategiesCorpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
        StrategiesCorpus <- tm_map(StrategiesCorpus, removePunctuation)
        StrategiesCorpus <- tm_map(StrategiesCorpus, stripWhitespace)
        dtm=TermDocumentMatrix(StrategiesCorpus)
        m=as.matrix(dtm)
        v=sort(rowSums(m), decreasing = T)
        d=data.frame(word=names(v), freq=v)
        if(nrow(d)!=0){
            Strategies=wordcloud(words = d$word, freq = d$freq, min.freq = 1,
                                 max.words=200, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35,
                                 colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
            print(Strategies)
        }
    })
    
    output$Strategies_FreqGraph=renderPlot({
        OpenEnds=OEReactive()
        StrategiesFrame=data.frame(doc_id=1:length(OpenEnds$Strategies), text=OpenEnds$Strategies)
        Strategies=DataframeSource(StrategiesFrame)
        StrategiesCorpus=Corpus(Strategies)
        StrategiesCorpus <- tm_map(StrategiesCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
        StrategiesCorpus <- tm_map(StrategiesCorpus, removeNumbers)
        StrategiesCorpus <- tm_map(StrategiesCorpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
        StrategiesCorpus <- tm_map(StrategiesCorpus, removePunctuation)
        StrategiesCorpus <- tm_map(StrategiesCorpus, stripWhitespace)
        dtm=TermDocumentMatrix(StrategiesCorpus)
        m=as.matrix(dtm)
        v=sort(rowSums(m), decreasing = T)
        d=data.frame(word=names(v), freq=v)
        
        topWords=head(d, 20)
        
        if(nrow(d)!=0){
            topWordsGraph=ggplot(topWords, aes(x=reorder(word, -freq), y=freq)) +geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill="#11294B")+
                theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12, angle = 45, hjust=1), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                      panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
                xlab("Top Twenty Most Frequent Words") +
                ylab("Frequency")+
                ggtitle(get_label(OpenEnds$Strategies))
            print(topWordsGraph)
        }
    })
    
    output$Strategies_Search=renderUI({
        OpenEnds=OEReactive()
        OpenEnds=as.data.frame(OpenEnds)
        if(input$Stratsearch=="Search Term"| input$Stratsearch==""){
            OEs=""
            HTML(OEs)
        }  else{
            Results=grep(input$Stratsearch, OpenEnds$Strategies)
            ResultOEs=OpenEnds$Strategies[Results]
            OEs=c()
            for (i in 1:length(ResultOEs)) {
                OEs[i]=paste(ResultOEs[i],"<br/> <br/>")
            }
            HTML(OEs)
        }
    })
    
    output$Strategies_Data=downloadHandler(
        #Code for download
        filename = function(){
            paste("Strategies", ".csv", sep = "")
        },
        content=function(file){
            OpenEnds=OEReactive()
            Results=grep(input$Stratsearch, OpenEnds$Strategies)
            ResultOEs=OpenEnds$Strategies[Results]
            ResultOEs=as.data.frame(ResultOEs)
            colnames(ResultOEs)=get_label(OpenEnds$Strategies)
            
            write.csv(ResultOEs, file, row.names = FALSE)
        }
        
    )
    
    
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce an error with that data and code. Selections do not change anything in the viewing panels, but there is no crash. (On Ubuntu with R 4.0.5). You should be posting the output of `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: I am away from my computer so I can't try that, but will as soon as I can. My concern is I think I have tried it, and since R is crashing while the app is running, the results of sessionInfo() prints info on a new R session. Is it possible to print this while the shiny app is running? Would it he helpful to include it in the app itself?

Comment: You should be able to run `sessionInfo()` before you run the shiny app. Generally true console crashes would be reported to the package authors since that's not ever supposed to be an acceptable failure mode. You also would be asked to make sure that you have the most recent version of all packages.